# Write pyomo .DAT File

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo, ampl

I have a .dat file for the parameters of my optimization:

```
 param: A:= 100;

 param: B:=
 1 0.5
 2 0.2
 3 0.3;
```

I am trying to reproduce the .dat file but with different values of A and B, I need to integrate it in a code so I wrote a script that writes strings to a .dat file but when I run in my model it produces an error. I believe it has something to do with the format, according to Pyomo the .dat file should be in AMPL format but there is little explanation on how to build such a file.

Currently doing this:

```
A = 100, B1 = '1 0.5', B2 = '2 0.2', B3 = '3 0.3'
file = open('ata.dat','w')
file.write('param: A:= '+str(A)+';\n')
file.write('param: B:=\n')
file.write(B1+'\n')
file.write(B2+'\n')
file.write(B3+';')
file.close()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Would it be easier for you to simply have your script build a `ConcreteModel` with the correct parameters rather than building the `dat` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample file gives an index for each element of B:

**1** 0.5

**2** 0.2

**3** 0.3

But it looks as if your code is only creating the values, not the indices:

0.5

0.2

0.3

AMPL .dat

As discussed in [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988808/declaring-a-tuple-of-parameters-in-ampl), when you're specifying an indexed parameter in AMPL, you generally need to state the indices explicitly; there are a couple of different ways to do this, but you can't just let them be implied by position. For more on AMPL data formats, see chapter 9 of [The AMPL Book](https://ampl.com/resources/the-ampl-book/chapter-downloads/).